# How to stop spaces,\n getting stripped from Unit Test Session Output?

Tags: f#, resharper

Resharper is compacting unit test std out / console output by filtering out all non alphanumeric characters.

```
Console.WriteLine("some text");
Console.WriteLine("more"); 

-> "sometextmore"
```

How can I stop this from happening?  Is there an option setting to make?

important: this appears to be a Resharper + F# only issue.  C# works as expected.  I suppose that's fair enough since Resharper is a C# tool.  However, if Resharper could work seamlessly as a test runner for both F# and C# this would be a welcome feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple wrapping of C# Console behaviour in F# printfn style.

NB. the printfn "no format" overload is not working for this work-around.

I'll award the question to the best answer if another answer shows up.

```
    // .fs code
    // --------

    namespace Play

    open PlayCS
    open System
    open NUnit.Framework

    module printHelper =
      let printfn (fmt: Format<_,_,_,_>) x = ConsoleHack.WriteLine <| sprintf fmt x        
    open printHelper

    [<TestFixture>]
    type  printPatterns2() =
      [<Test>]
      member __.testHelper() = 
        printfn "%s" "our overloaded printfn"
        printfn "%s" "now does"
        printfn "%s" "what"
        printfn "%s" "it is supposed to"
        printfn "%s" "in the F#/Resharper/nunit context"

      [<Test>]
      member __.testHackWriteLine() = 
        ConsoleHack.WriteLine(sprintf "%s" "abc")
        ConsoleHack.WriteLine(sprintf "%s" "abc")

    // .cs code
    // --------

    using System;

    namespace PlayCS
    {
        public class ConsoleHack
        {
            public static void WriteLine(string s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Improvement requests:

- is it possible to load this into the top-level-domain?

Comment: Unless you are on [F# 3.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) performance of tests using `printfn` would be significantly poorer, than the same using `Console.WriteLine`, if this factor somehow matters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what would cause a problem like this. Out of completely random curiosity, what happens if you tried either " " or "%20" for your white space?  I'm not sure what you could do about the line break, maybe try putting an actual "\n" in the string.

Comment: I did try \n and \r\n, but those got stripped out too.